# laravel: avoid miscellaneous parameters in get method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-request

For example I have this url:

http://127.0.0.1/public?valid=test1&invalid=test2

So I send 2 parameters to a related function in its controller:

```
       $input = $request->all();
       $validator = Validator::make($input, [
         'valid' => 'nullable|string',
       ]);

       if ($validator->fails())
       {
         return back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
       }
```

I expect this url works:

```
http://127.0.0.1/public?valid=test1
```

But for this:
    http://127.0.0.1/public?invalid=test2

I do not want this url works because I do not define `invalid` parameter in Validator (The route accepted that URL):

Dose laravel support to refuse miscellaneous parameters?

The laravel website has that bug too

```
https://laravel.com/?asd=asd
```

My solution:

```
$input = $request->all();
$valid = ['valid'];
foreach($input as $key => $val)
{
   if(!in_array($key,$valid)) abort(404);
}
```

Comment: To throw the 404 if any non-valid parameters are passed, you could do: `if ($request->except('valid')) abort(404);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$request->only()` to get just the parameters you want:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input

```
$data = $request->only(['valid_1', 'valid_2']);
```

Comment: I tried this method before. yes it remove other parameters, but not return for example 404 page for incorrect URL. So seo problem remains.